# Where is the gcc library link stored in Rstudio. I need to change it

Tags: gcc, server, rstudio

I am working with a Rstudio installed on a Centos server. The default gcc is version 4.4.7 but the lubridate package needs a higher version. I now have one installed but Rstudio still is pointing to the old one. When I run `system2("gcc", "--version")` in the console I get `gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)`.
But when I run R in the Rstudio terminal and then enter the system2 code I get `gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)`

How do I change the gcc that Rstudio uses when it compiles packages?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a comprehensive answer but the way I solved my problem was to set the path that Rstudio uses to be the same as the PATH variable in the linux system. `Sys.getenv()` shows all the environment variables used by Rstudio. `Sys.setenv(PATH = "xxx")` sets the PATH to xxx. Not sure how Rstudio got a different PATH but when I changed it I was able to compile `lubridate`. Along the way I may have changed some other things that ultimately made this work but I didn't keep track of those.